# Moving Windows XP system to newer hardware causes crash

Tags: windows, boot, windows-xp

I am trying to move a 32-bit Windows XP Home system from an Intel D875PBZ motherboard (Pentium 4, PATA HDD) to a Gigabyte GA-78LMT-USB3 (AMD, 64-bit, quad core, PATA HDD) without losing any programs/settings. I proved that 32-bit XP can be installed on the newer computer by doing a fresh installation (XP SP2 CD-ROM, no extra drivers). Now I want move the old system over, but it crashes during booting, even when choosing Safe Mode.

Originally, I got BSODs early in the boot process, but after using RegEditPE to copy over the System branch from the fresh installation's registry, it now gets to where the loading animation disappears, a mouse pointer is displayed (it looks a little large though, as though it's using a low graphics resolution), shows a green-blue screen and then reboots itself, seemingly right before the "Loading personal settings..." pop-up box, which is right before the desktop would show.

I looked at a loaded-driver log, but everything looks okay there.  And I read up on the XP boot process, but the descriptions were a little vague.  How can I discover (log) what is happening at this point?

Comment: Windows was not designed to be migrated to dissimilar hardware. There is third-party software that makes this possible but they are not compatible with Windows XP.  The log your looking for doesn’t exist.

Comment: Clean reinstall of XP is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things over many months; the best guess I've heard so far is that there is some driver incompatibility that occurs when Windows begins to load/show the desktop.

I never learned how to log the *entire* driver-loading process during boot-up.

That said, there was one thing I haven't tried: Macrium Reflect's ReDeploy feature which supposedly specializes in adding/loading proper drivers for the new target hardware when restoring a backup image of the old machine.  Since there was no guarantee that came with the (presently) $75 purchase price, and for other reasons, I eventually settled upon doing a fresh installation instead.

I posted this half-answer here since it may help someone and obviously my goal was the OS migration more so than the logging of the boot-up drivers.

Comment: The answer as commenters suggested to you a month ago was to reinstall. You have a full answer here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @music2myear.  I didn't feel right calling it a full answer because my original question was 'How do I log/follow the booting process?'  And I eventually gave up. :)